# how to change react-select style options with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I am trying to change the style options for my react-select component (specifically trying to get rid of the border and change the font and text color) but am not sure how to fix the TypeScript errors.  I have the following code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Select, { ValueType } from 'react-select';

type OptionType = {
    value: string;
    label: string;
  };

const LanguageSelector = () => {
    const languageOptions: OptionType[] = [
        { value: 'English', label: 'EN' },
        { value: 'German', label: 'DE' },
        { value: 'French', label: 'FR' },
      ];
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState<ValueType<OptionType, false>>(languageOptions[0]);
    const handleChange = (option: ValueType<OptionType, false>) => setSelectedOption(option);
    const customStyles = value => ({
        control: (provided, state) => ({
          ...provided,
          alignItems: "baseline",
          backgroundColor: value ? "gray" : "white"
        })
      });

    return (
    <div>
        <Select
            value={selectedOption}
            onChange={handleChange}
            options={languageOptions}
            styles={customStyles}
        />
    </div>
    )
};

export default LanguageSelector;
```

The errors are that `provided`, `state`, and `value` all implicitly have an 'any' type.
I'm assuming `provided` would have type `CSSProperties`, but am unsure about `state`. Does anyone know what these types should be?

Comment: what is the meaning of Control, provided and state here?

Comment: @sbuck89 Does my answer solves your problem?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you don't need the customStyles to be a function (as you are not using the value at all.)

Secondly, can add type to your customStyles with StylesConfig type, which expects **OptionType, false** as two generics.

```
const dropdownStyles: StylesConfig<OptionType, false> = {
  container: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    flexGrow: 1,
  }),
  control: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    background: '#fff',
    borderColor: '#9e9e9e',
    minHeight: '24px',
  }),
}
```

As a plus, you could even use OptionTypeBase from their types if you don't have extra properties in your options array's properties.